# Adding a new class property == new API version?

Tags: c#, api

I have the following code:

```
public class Car
{
    public int numberOfWheels { get; set; }
    public string colour { get; set; }

    public Car(int numberOfWheels, string colour)
    {
        this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
        this.colour = colour;
    }
}

[Route("/")]
public class CarController: Controller
{
    [Route("api/v1")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Car>> Get()
    {
        return new List<Car> { new Car(4, "yellow") };
    }
}
```

The above is an API call (`http://<host>/car/v1`) that results in a `List` of objects of type `Car` being retrieved and returned.

If I were to update the `Car` property to now capture Brand property:

```
public class Car
{
    public int numberOfWheels { get; set; }
    public string colour { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; } // Now capturing Brand

    public Car(int numberOfWheels, string colour, string brand)
    {
        this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.brand = brand;
    }
}
```

Is this a strong enough momentum to warrant a new API version to be created to reflect the delta?

```
[Route("api/v1/Car")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> Get()
{
    var listOfCars = (new List<Car> { new Car(4, "yellow", "Volvo") });

    return listOfCars.Select(c => new { c.colour, c.numberOfWheels });
}

[Route("api/v1.1/Car")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Car>> GetCarWithMoreProperties()
{
    return new List<Car> { new Car(4, "yellow", "Volvo") };
}
```

Comment: I'm post this as a comment because this will probably be closed or moved from code review.   Generally I would say no.  Unless it breaks an existing client.  Most consumers of the json result will just ignore extra properties coming back.  If you removed a property then yes.  If you add an new end point I would say no.  It's all about is it a breaking change to existing clients.  Now this is something of a business decision.   This is probably better suited for the Software Engineering stack site then code review.

Comment: The definition of [breaking change](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breaking_change): *A change in one part of a software system that potentially causes other components to fail;*. It says that if your clients can't communicate with your API **without code change** then you have broken the backward compatibility. So, you have to separate that version from previous one. If your API is usable without any further adjustment on the client-side then you don't have to increase the version.

Comment: @CharlesNRice: While it may feel like a pedantic distinction to what you were saying, I'd like to extend that "version" is a bit too ambiguous. You're correct that the _major_ version only changes for _breaking_ changes, but the minor version can be updated even if the change is not breaking. While APIs tend to only use major versioning, OP is specifically using `v1` and `v1.1`, which is a minor version upgrade, not a major one.

Comment: @Flater I think that's a business decision, why I called that out in my first comment.  For a lot of projects that would create a lot of versions and maintenance issues if every change was a new version even if minor version change.  Some project that have infrequent changes or stable it might work but for teams that work in 2 week sprints this seems it could quickly get out of hand.  Again maybe that's right call but there is more info needed to know if right call for each project/business.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 1):

In view the extra property is *highly unlikely* to cause a breaking change (unless for some reason the consumer tracks the `count` of properties returned from the API call for whatever reason), the answer is this extra property does not warrant the need to create an additional version.